# mongodb find $text search query is changed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I am running into some weird behavior in my mongo environment when using the $text operator.  I am getting results back when I am expecting none.  I expect the string ABCD to match, but there are no entries that contain ACBDE.  a wild card index for text is defined('$**': text)

As you can see in the explain the parsed text query is modifying what I have in $search.  Any ideas of what might be going on?

```
> db.catalogentries.find({$text: {$search: 'abcde'}}).pretty().explain()
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.catalogentries",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$text" : {
                                "$search" : "abcde",
                                "$language" : "english",
                                "$caseSensitive" : false,
                                "$diacriticSensitive" : false
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "TEXT",
                        "indexPrefix" : {

                        },
                        "indexName" : "$**_text",
                        "parsedTextQuery" : {
                                "terms" : [
                                        "abcd"
                                ],
                                "negatedTerms" : [ ],
                                "phrases" : [ ],
                                "negatedPhrases" : [ ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "TEXT_MATCH",
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "TEXT_OR",
                                        "inputStage" : {
                                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                "keyPattern" : {
                                                        "_fts" : "text",
                                                        "_ftsx" : 1
                                                },
                                                "indexName" : "$**_text",
                                                "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                "isUnique" : false,
                                                "isSparse" : false,
                                                "isPartial" : false,
                                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                                "direction" : "backward",
                                                "indexBounds" : {

                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "mongo01",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.4",
                "gitVersion" : "e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

It also should be noted that if I search ACBDF, ABCDD, or ABC that I get no results as expected.

Comment: Thanks JohnnyHK! That appears to have solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your search term isn't an actual word, then you should add `$language: 'none'` to your query to disable word stemming that can lead to unexpected results like this.

So change your query to:

```
db.catalogentries.find({$text: {$search: 'abcde', $language: 'none'}})
```